# Xcode 9.1 fails on startup - UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException)

Tags: xcode, crash, startup

I've installed Xcode 9.1 and I'm not able to start Xcode. The error's output is here https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25947243/. Looks like some plugin(s) can't be loaded. There was a suggestion to clean `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins` directory, but I don't have such a directory. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, maybe it would help someone else. I just ran the following command: 
`sudo installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg -target /`